# ggplot facet_wrap bar chart and column width

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a following data frame and a bar chart using `ggplot` and `facet_wrap()`.

```
group <- c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f')
condition_a <- c('occasionally', 'often', 'often', 'often', 'occasionally', 'often', 'often', 'occasionally', 'often', 'often', 'occasionally', 'occasionally', 'often', 'often', 'occasionally')
condition_c <- c('yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no')

data.frame <- data_frame (group, condition_a, condition_c)

tiff("test.tiff", units="in", width=15, height=5, res=300)
ggplot(data.frame, aes(x = condition_a, fill = condition_c)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  geom_bar(position = position_fill()) +
  facet_wrap(~ group)
dev.off()
```

The problem is that the columns are way too wide, and I would like to fit all those charts side by side. I have tried geom_col and geom_bar, but they don't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried reducing the width argument in your call to `tiff`: the ggplot image is filling the area of your tiff image. Try with say `width = 6`. Alternatively if you need the image to be 15 inches in width, increase the tiff height to suit the relative bar width and height of the plot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I change the tiff width, the colums go narrower. But still there are three charts side by side, and the rest below?

Comment: Try with `facet_wrap(~ group, nrow = 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `facet_grid( ~ group)`. This also becomes useful for faceting by two groups, when `facet_grid(group1 ~ group2)` would be used.